# How to set selected option value for dynamically added combo list using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically added dropdown list using jquery ajax.

once I added, I need to get the value of user selected dropdown items,

**myPage.aspx**

```
<select class="form-control" id="cbVebdorAccount" style="padding:1px 10px;">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>

</select>
```

**Jquery**

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
    $('#cbVebdorAccount').append($('<option>', {
        value: data.d[i].values,
        text: data.d[i].Accountnumber
    }));
}
```

**I tried the below code**

```
$('#cbVebdorAccount').change(function () {
    $(this).find('option').prop('selected', true)
    console.log('work'+$(this).val());
});
```

**UPDATE After Ajax Call html element**

```
<select class="form-control" id="cbVebdorAccount" style="padding:1px 10px;">
    <option value="2">3333</option>
    <option value="3">56211122</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The first line of your `change` handler is not necessary. The second line should work just fine. Have you checked that your AJAX call is returning the correct results and that the `select` is properly formed after that call?

Comment: What do you want to do?

1) add a new option and then set it as selected?
Or
2) add a new option and then get the selected option?

Comment: @TheKNVB I always get the value of what i select at first time. when  I again change second time. it's still getting what i selected first time.

Comment: That's because the first line in your handler causes the first `option` to become selected. Remove that line as it is the problem.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are correct bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove line `$(this).find('option').prop('selected', true)` and try to use `$(this).find("option:selected").val()` instead or simply `$(this).val()` like:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('#cbVebdorAccount').append($('<option>', {
    value: i + 3,
    text: i + 3
  }));
}

$('#cbVebdorAccount').change(function() {
  var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  console.log('works: ' + $(this).val());
  console.log('This also works: ' + value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="cbVebdorAccount" style="padding:1px 10px;">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```